# npm install how to prevent nested node_mocules folders

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I have a `package.json` file that has

```
"dependencies": {
 "packageA": "^1.0.0",
```

and this `package A` has another dependency in his `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
 "packageA_B": "^1.0.0",
```

Then, if I run `npm install` on `windows 10`, `node v11.11.0` I end up having

```
/node_modules/packageA
/node_modules/packageA/node_modules/packageA_B
```

Then, if I delete this package and run `npm install packageA` I end up having

```
/node_modules/packageA
/node_modules/packageA_B
```

Which is what I want from the beginning. Why is this inconsistency happening? How to force to install all packages in a non-nested way?

```
package.json

{
  "name": "first_package",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "gatsby-config.js",
  "version": "0.2.25",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA": "git+https://blah.git#h5c8f72",

    "gatsby": "2.1.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages": "^1.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.24",
    "gatsby-plugin-page-creator": "^2.0.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.23",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.15",

    "path": "0.12.7",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "styled-icons": "^7.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-help": "^1.6.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.app/unit-testing\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://"
  }
}
```

```
Package A package.json

{
  "name": "packageA",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.2.25",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA_B": "0.2.25",

    "styled-components": "4.2.0",
    "styled-icons": "7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "3.0.7",

    "gatsby-plugin-page-creator": "2.0.12",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "2.0.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages": "1.1.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "esm": "3.2.14",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",

    "gatsby-plugin-gtag": "1.0.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.0.26",
    "react-cookie-consent": "2.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "gatsby": "2.1.4",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gatsby": "2.1.4",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",

    "babel-eslint": "^10.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-help": "^1.6.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.app/unit-testing\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

```
Package A_B package.json

{
  "name": "packageA_B",
  "version": "0.2.25",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "4.2.0",
    "styled-icons": "7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "3.0.7",

    "gatsby-plugin-page-creator": "2.0.12",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "2.0.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages": "1.1.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "esm": "3.2.14",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",

    "gatsby-mdx": "0.4.2",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "0.20.3",
    "@mdx-js/tag": "0.20.3",
    "gatsby-image": "2.0.31",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "2.0.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "2.0.32",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.1.17",
    "react-helmet": "5.2.0",
    "react-share": "2.4.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "gatsby": "2.1.4",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gatsby": "2.1.4",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",

    "babel-eslint": "^10.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-help": "^1.6.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.app/unit-testing\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the packages? It's not supposed to happen if you run `npm install` in the root dir of your project (where `package.json` is located)

Comment: My packages (gatsby themes). So I have package A that requires B and B that requires C, if I install A, then C is nested in B where C and B should be at the same level. But if I do `npm install A` instead of `npm install` (that relies on package.json), then it gets right.Also, if once installed I delete them from `node_modules`, then a `npm install` works as expected (not nested). Why is this happening in the first place? Because if the nesting thing happens then the site doesn't work

Comment: Please tell me the exact name of the packages

Comment: They are private. I'll try to make them public so that you can reproduce it, but won't be immediate. Anyway, your point is that what I'm describing should not occur (?), so that packages should never be installed in a nested way (?)

Comment: Exactly. There is a problem with the packages themselves, possibly in their install or postInstall scripts

Comment: Well in this sense there's nothing strange in the packages, I paste the package.json in the answer, no post-scripts

Comment: @NinoFiliu indeed, now I've just done a fresh `npm install` and `packageA` and `packageA_B` appear at `/node_modules`, this is not nested, **but** each one of them has a `node_modules` folder with repeated packages inside. Why is this happening? If versions are the same there's no reason of having nested duplicates, isn't it?

Comment: Apparently, this is solved by not specifying an exact version `"1.0.0"` but a compatible one `"^1.0.0"`, for which I don't see nested folders anymore

Answer (score 0):

Solved by specifying not an exact version `"1.0.0"` but a compatible version `"^1.0.0"`. Somehow with the exact version npm doesn't share the package even though they are the exact same version. Also, running `npm dedupe` doesn't make anything when an exact version is specified.